# SlidingUp panel in map fragment similar to google maps

Tags: android, mapfragment

I am using this for slide up layout in my map fragment but my app just crashing again and again and I don't understand what's happening. In bug report it just saying Binary XML file line #34 Binary XML file line #34: "Error inflating class fragment".

> https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

this is my MapsActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        app:umanoOverlay="true"
        app:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        app:umanoParalaxOffset="100dp"
        app:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tree_button"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tree" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ecology"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity">
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/bottom_data">
        </include>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

BottomData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tex1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="EXPLORE "
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tex1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Your Place" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="My Place" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Many to find " />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

Android studio alos provide map activity.. you can add easily.

add below dependency into app level gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

after that your error solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      tools:context=".MapsActivity"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: I asked something else..look into my MapsActivity.xml I already Implemented Maps fragment into my project I just want to implement SlideUpPanel onto it. :)

Comment: you have facing this error Error inflating class fragment .. that solution is you add  this dependency into app level gradle file..implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

I believe u are using the umano slider the wrong way.

1. The `com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout` has to be the `root element` in your `activity layout`
2. The `layout` must have `gravity` set to either `top` or `bottom`(position the slider will draw from)
3. Make sure that it has **two children**. The first child is your `main layout`. The second child is your `layout` for the sliding up panel
4. The `main layout` should have the `width` and the `height` set to `match_parent`.
   The `sliding layout` should have the `width` set to `match_parent` and the `height` set to either `match_parent`, `wrap_content`

This would be an example:

```
//main_activity.xml or whatever layout u wish

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp">//Height when the slide panel is in the collapsed form

    //This is the base content, everything u want in the view has to be inside these
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </fragment>

    //This is the sliding layout, everything u want in the slider has to be here
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingLayoutMapsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Anyway, u need to add this into the gradle files

```
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
```

This is from https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 0):

look at this code

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    sothree:setAnchorPoint="middle"
    >

<!-- Main here -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.eminent.a2019.mapslearnign.MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- SlideUpPanelHere -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
</LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```